# Mathematica notebook messed up

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

During the last weeks a strange problem occured several times with my notebooks. Sometimes when I open up a notebook the content is completely messed up in the sense, that it is put into one cell. That means, that every cell I was able to execute independently is now gone and I am left with one cell. Even the "In[%]:=" and "Out[%]:=" are now inside the cell and the whole thing can't be executed.

Here is a example:

[image]

The Problem occurs randomly and does have nothing to do with the content. I guess it is some kind of formatting problem!? I use Ubuntu 12.04 and Mathematica 8. Pls help, fixing notebooks like this by hand is really tedious!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `Switch` cannot find a match for your operating system, which I presume is Linux.  There are only matches for "Unix" and "Windows" in your first line.

Once you have added a match for your OS the rest will probably work fine.

Examples including `Switch` failing :-

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris! No, there is no problem with the Switch. I do use Linux and Mathematica detects it as Unix. I dont think my problem has anything to do with the actual code anyways. I edited my question to make that clear. Thx